# can kotlin annotation processor be add properties using Kotlin annotation processor?

Tags: kotlin, annotation-processing, kapt

Lombok in Java can. But I wonder if it's possible in Kotlin.

Looking at the documentation for KAPT, and how to use the KAPT implementation plugin, it doesn't seem possible. Is my understanding correct?
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#keep-java-compiler-s-annotation-processors
https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet